# How to remove negative sign to left in notebad++?

Tags: notepad++

[image]

as shown minus sign appears to right. How could i fix it to the left?

Comment: Would you consider a Python script as an option?

Comment: @goodvibration I would :-) ... especially in the context of doing this in a software team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this find and replace:

**Find:**

```
(\d+\.\d+)-
```

**Replace:**

```
-$1
```

The strategy used here is to capture all numbers which end in a minus sign, and then to replace such matches with a leading minus sign followed by the captured number.

Follow the demo link below to see the regex in action.  If the regex does not work for you, then you have data different than what you posted in the question.  Perhaps the minus sign you have is actually a different character than what I assume?

### Demo

Comment: @RanaSobhy Check the "minus" sign you are using.  I used a hyphen but maybe in your text it is something other than this.  Look at the demo I included.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a python script:

```
def Fix(num):
    return '-'+num[:-1] if num.endswith('-') else num

fileDesc = open(FILE_NAME,'r')
data = fileDesc.read()
fileDesc.close()

data = ','.join([Fix(num) for num in data.split(',')])

fileDesc = open(FILE_NAME,'w')
fileDesc.write(data)
fileDesc.close()
```

Comment: P.S.: wrote it directly here without even testing, so give it a try an let me know if it works for you...

Comment: unfortunate,i don't use python